# Protobuf Trip Updates Full

Tags: real-time, protobuf-net

I am writing and reading data to and from .pb files
But how do I get to write an output like the example that shows the documentation from my generated FeedMessage class?
Example sample:
https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/trip-updates-full

Comment: you have tagged protobuf-net; are you *actually* using protobuf-net? if so: just run the object model through your choice of JSON serializer to get *something* human readable - it won't be exactly as shown though, because that is just a *random ASCII representation* of the data - no serializer is going to include the comments, for example; usually, when talking about protobuf, you want the binaryu format

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.
I have used JsonSerializer.Serialize and Google.Protobuf.JsonFormatter
Can you show an example?